# PHP inconsistent var_dump, wrong floor result with a float calulation

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal, var-dump

For this code:

```
$value = 200.1;
$denominator = 0.1;
echo "value: $value\n";
echo "denominator: $denominator\n";

$resultInt = ($value / $denominator);
echo "($value / $denominator) = ";
printf ("%f\n", $resultInt);

$resultInt = (int) ($value / $denominator);
echo "(int) ($value / $denominator) = ";
printf ("%f\n", $resultInt);

$resultInt = floor($value / $denominator);
echo "floor($value / $denominator) = ";
printf ("%f\n", $resultInt);

$resultInt = floor((int) ($value / $denominator));
echo "floor((int) ($value / $denominator)) = ";
printf ("%f\n", $resultInt);

$resultInt = floor((float) 2001);
echo "floor((float) 2001) = ";
printf ("%f\n", $resultInt);

$resultInt = round($value / $denominator, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
echo "round($value / $denominator, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) = ";
printf ("%f\n", $resultInt);

$valueMul = $resultInt * $denominator;
if ($valueMul !== $value) {
    echo "they are not the same\n";
    var_dump($value);
    var_dump($valueMul);
}

$valueDiff = $value - $valueMul;
if ($valueDiff !== 0) {
    echo "valueDiff is not zero\n";
    var_dump($valueDiff);
}
```

I have this result:

```
value: 200.1
denominator: 0.1
(200.1 / 0.1) = 2001.000000
(int) (200.1 / 0.1) = 2000.000000
floor(200.1 / 0.1) = 2000.000000
floor((int) (200.1 / 0.1)) = 2000.000000
floor((float) 2001) = 2001.000000
round(200.1 / 0.1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) = 2001.000000
they are not the same
float(200.1)
float(200.1)
valueDiff is not zero
float(-2.8421709430404E-14)
```

The expected result for all calculations above is 2001, but in some cases it is 2000.

I am aware about fractions not being stored in variables as decimals due to the fact the computer operates on binaries.

But as manual of [floor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) states:

> floor — **Round** fractions down

therefore I would expect the same result as with:

```
round(200.1 / 0.1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
```

but round returns 2001 as expected and floor returns 2000 (wrong).

Do you know why?

I also see that `var_debug` is inconsistent:

for the code:

```
$resultInt = round($value / $denominator, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
echo "round($value / $denominator, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) = ";
printf ("%f\n", $resultInt);

$valueMul = $resultInt * $denominator;
if ($valueMul !== $value) {
    echo "they are not the same\n";
    var_dump($value);
    var_dump($valueMul);
}
```

it displays both values as the same (but they aren't):

```
they are not the same
float(200.1)
float(200.1)
```

but for diff of them

```
$valueDiff = $value - $valueMul;
if ($valueDiff !== 0) {
    echo "valueDiff is not zero\n";
    var_dump($valueDiff);
}
```

it prints non zero value

So in one case it prints both values as the same but a result of subtracting one from the other is not printed as a zero - why?

What function one can use in PHP to always see the true value of a float or an integer and not its fussy-decimal representation?
I mean for the output:

```
they are not the same
float(200.1)
float(200.1)
```

I should see different values, not the same.

And what is a function to print decimal representation of floats in consistent manner?
I mean if in the example

```
they are not the same
float(200.1)
float(200.1)
```

floats are printed exactly the same (even if they aren't in fact) then in the example:

```
valueDiff is not zero
float(-2.8421709430404E-14)
```

the same function should print 0 consequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into precision issues. You should never trust floating point numbers to the last digit in PHP.

From the manual ([Floating Point Numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)), there's even a point about your specific test numbers in the second paragraph:

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
> the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
> which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
> of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
> errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
> several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
> floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
> exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
> used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
> cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
> small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
> example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
> expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
> 7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
> compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
> precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
> functions are available.
>
> For a "simple" explanation, see the [» floating point guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/) that's also
> titled "Why don’t my numbers add up?"

Try using the [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) or [gmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) functions if you need that kind of precision.

And here's a relevant page from the floating point guide referenced in the manual: https://floating-point-gui.de/languages/php/

Comment: @EBP thank you for the useful links, do you have any idea how to substitute inconsistent `var_dump` displaying for both variables the same `float(200.1)` where they definitely  different?

Comment: @Jimmix You mean to get the `var_dump` to display something closer to what's actually stored? You can use `ini_set` to set precision really high when you call var_dump. For instance, on my machine, when I call `ini_set('precision', 25);` and then `var_dump(200 + 0.1)` and `var_dump(200 + 0.3 - 0.2);` I get `float(200.0999999999999943156581)` and `float(200.1000000000000227373675)` - However, be aware that this will also cause your echo statements to have lots of extra decimal positions as well.

Comment: @EBP Yes that's exactly what I was after, I think I did something similar someday without ini_set if I'm not wrong but I can't recall the way i did it. Could the same result be achieved by sort of param for prinf instead of ini_set?

Comment: @Jimmix Yes, for example with `printf('%.20f', $floatingpointvariable);`